# How to detect screen overlay in android?

Tags: android

In some devices, there is no action when click vpn permission ok button, while screen overlay application is running.
So i want to check screen overlay application is running, and make 'Screen Overay detected' dialog.

Is there anyway to detect screen overlay programmatically in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sample code**

```
public void checkDrawOverlayPermission(Context context) {
    // check if we already  have permission to draw over other apps
    if (Settings.canDrawOverlays(context)) {
        // code
    } else {
        // if not construct intent to request permission
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
        // request permission via start activity for result
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
```

**Inside onActivityResult check permission again**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // check if received result code
    // is equal our requested code for draw permission
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        // if so check once again if we have permission
         if (Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
        // continue here - permission was granted

    }
    }
}
```

**And if u want to handle Screen Overlay Detected PopUp  Programatically?**
This should help, https://gist.github.com/Aeonitis/2337b1ca652173839395be82db7d05c3

Comment: I believe the original question was to check if an app is using an overlay, not if the current app can use overlay.

Answer (score -3):

Use Lint (on menu go to Analyze > Inspect Code...). If there is any screen overlay on your project, it will tell you.